# Accessing 2 clusters with the same kubeconfig

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

In the case that there are 2 clusters of kubernetes A and B, being exact replicas, and a DNS entry for the kubernetes API that, some days points to A and other days points to B, how can I do to have a single kubeconfig so that the kubectl user does not notice the difference ?

Can I deploy (with Kops) a cluster B using the same credentials and certificates as A ?

Comment: Do you have exact replicas or are you asking how to setup replicated clusters? kubectl credential authorisation is not really a problem if you have solved the replication bit. At the mininum you would want a [shared certificate authority](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/custom_ca/)

Comment: What's your use case? Is it just for switching between them? If yes, have you checked `kubectl config use-context`?